# Making this a loop without copy pasting over and over Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
message.channel.send(embed1).then((msgg) => setTimeout(() => {
    const opponentData = userHit(opponentp, userPet.stats.strength, userPet, opponentPet, userp)
    const userData = opponentHit(userp, opponentPet.stats.strength, userPet, opponentPet, opponentp)

    if (opponentData.health >= 1) {
      msgg.edit(opponentData.embed)
    }
    
    if (userData.health >= 1) {
      msgg.edit(userData.embed)
    }
  }, 1000))
}
```

So ... I have this code, and I have been stumped for a few days. I need to loop these so they run one after the other until on hits 0 or lower without copy pasting them over and over. I need it to stop editing the message after it hits 0 or lower.

Comment: What exactly do you need to run multiple times?

Comment: ```if (opponentData.health >= 1) {
            msgg.edit(opponentData.embed)
          }
        
          if (userData.health >= 1) {
            msgg.edit(userData.embed)```

The message editing to new embed

Comment: is there something that triggers the function to run again? the part you dont want to repeat, is having these 2 `if`s? I'm not really understanding what you want

Comment: I want to find a way to trigger the two if statements to loop over and over one after the other until one returns 0 or lower ...

Comment: But to keep running it non-stop? If you keep running just the `if`s non-stop, it will never return 0, because it will block the rest of the code from executing, so the value will be static. When does the health actually changes? Thats when you should run your `if`s

Comment: My health changes in the ```const opponentData = userHit(opponentp, userPet.stats.strength, userPet, opponentPet, userp)
    const userData = opponentHit(userp, opponentPet.stats.strength, userPet, opponentPet, opponentp)``` part ... Those are two separate functions that update the arrays when run ...

Comment: So I got it to loop by changing setTimeout to setInterval but now I don't know how to clear the interval ...

Comment: Instead of returning a `setInterval` open brackets, then do `const interval = setInterval...`.
When you need to stop, just do a `clearInterval(interval)`

Answer (score 0):

**To loop this** code **you have to use** simple **`do while`** **method**!
**Read** more **about this** method [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while). Mozilla documentation is very helpful!
I hope I helped you with this.
Have a nice day!